# Getting Price Format with getAttributeRawValue

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price

I have this code to get the price of related products in new order email:

```
<?php echo Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($relatedProductId, 'price', $storeId); ?>
```

It outputs the price but in the incorrect format like this **19.9700** with extra zeros. I've tried several ways to get it to remove the extra zeros but everything I can find Google doesn't show how this is done with **getAttributeRawValue**. How can I get the show the correct price format like **19.97**? Thank you

Comment: Are you aware that using the raw attribute value will not take special prices into account?

Comment: No i wasn't aware of that. How does one get the special price if the item has one?

Comment: The best way is to load the related products collection and directly include the price data with `$collection->addPriceData()`, then use `$product->getFinalPrice()` on the collection items. This fetches all price data from the price index and applies group price, special price etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format the price as per your store currency for this. You can try with this code :

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice(Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($relatedProductId, 'price', $storeId), false); ?>
```

Method `getAttributeRawValue` will return raw value from DB in which it is stored and since Magento stores decimal values upto 4 places after decimal point, you are getting those extra 0s.

Comment: It worked. Thank you