# Price format custom product price attribute

Tags: price, product-attribute, magento-2.1

I've got [this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107037/getting-price-format-with-getattributerawvalue), but in Magento 2.1.
I added a "Starting From" price attribute to all products, and want to call that on the category listing. Because Magento2 supports price-type attributes, I thought this would work out of the box.

But when I enter a price of €2,95 it shows 295.000 on the frontend. The aformentioned issue had a solution with price-formatting helper, but I can't seem to find the correct one for Magento 2.1 - anyone any ideas?